# Insulating back of wall from attic space

Tags: walls, insulation, energy-efficiency

I have a 3rd floor area with a crawl space all around it with some failing 2x4 bats of insulation, the critters and age have it rolling off the back side of the walls. I was just going to place the insulation back in there and use some metal insulation support rods to keep it from falling again...but some areas are beyond that repair.

What type of rolled insulation should I use from this side of the wall to be most effective? I was thinking unfaced r13 and using some support rods here and there? I feel like this could getting annoying but it needs be done.

Comment: I'm not sure what a crawl space is doing under a 3rd floor area.  Can you post pics. I cannot imagine this in my head.

Comment: @RMDman Post says *around* not underneath. Threw me off as well. My assumption would be some half walls tying into a roof pitch and an *attic* space around them.

Comment: @matt,  I would never have thought of the 1/2 walls being described as "crawl space".

Comment: @RMDman Understandable, another reason why pictures are so helpful when it comes to things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider rockwool rather than fiberglass un-faced batts - they have a bit more solidity and may stay put better when stuffed in place.

But that's certainly a generally sound plan. Support from the backside may be easier with wires strung across multiple stud bays attached to the studs by screws than fiddling with jamming rods into each stud bay individually.

An alternative would be to use a layer of rigid rockwool board, homasote, or EPS foam (all vapor permeable) over the studs on the attic (kneewall, crawlspace) side holding the un-faced batts in place. That holds the batts, *and* adds additional insulation value, the most significant of which is breaking the thermal bridge of the wooden studs, which are typically 1.5 inches of about R5 every 16-24 inches between the R13 batts.

Comment: +1 for thermal break.  I think this is a very under appreciated concept.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, I had thought about doing the ridgid board on the stud faces. Thank you. Is there a certain type of thin wire you would recommend for holding up the batts?

Comment: Whatever's affordable, which usually is going to mean galvanized steel; but you don't need it at all if you use insulation boards over, they will hold the batts in place.